# Parallelize alsmot random read and writes into memory

Tags: multithreading, math, rust, parallel-processing, simulation

I am doing a fluid simulation that I want to parallelize, I am going to simplify the logic into the only  part that matters for this question. A kernel would look something like in pseudo code(:

```rs
fn update(particle : &mut Particle, grid : &mut Grid)
{
   let grid_index = to_grid_index(particle.pos);

   for i in -1..=1
   {
      for j in -1..=1
      {
         grid[grid_index + IVec2(i, j)] += grid[grid_index + IVec2(j, i)];
      }
   }

   particle.pos.update();
}
```

Said otherwise the logic is:

- Read data from a grid around the position of a particle.
- Modify it.
- Write it back into the positions that it was read from.

The issue here is that many particles my be close to each other, meaning some or all of the 9 cells overlap for each particle. The naive solution is to add a mutex per cell in the grid and to lock it whenever a read or write is to be made.

However after testing, this leads to what is essentially a single threaded application, because all the threads are constantly locking and waiting for each other.

Is there a pattern I can use to parallelize the code?

Comment: You need _some_ protection against data races. Can you use atomics?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the code is doing. What is `Grid`? What is `IVec2`? Depending on the details of your algorithm, you can operate on separate grids in different threads and only combine them back into a single grid every so often.

Comment: The code you gave looks suspicious to me. If other threads can change the grid data at any time, the outcome won't be deterministic, even with locking or atomics.

Comment: @SvenMarnach the outcome is mathematically deterministic. The threads are computing addition. So it doesn;t matter the order in which things are updated, the final reslt is the same.

Comment: @Makogan It looks like you are adding the current value of some grid cell to a grid cell in each loop iteration. In which it totally _does_ matter whether this grid cell was just modified by a different thread or not, since you'd be adding a different number.

Comment: However, if the order really doesn't matter, you can give each thread its own grid, and add all grids in the end. This will be way faster than trying to synchronize between threads.

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is  I think the correct way to go about it.

Comment: @Makogan If this is a reasonably large simulation, your bottleneck will probably be memory bandwidth. Make sure each thread uses "local" memory if you are on a ccNUMA architecture.